# calculating oracle users average session time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit-trail

How to write a **PL/SQL program** to calculate and display the username and average session time for all database users in oracle 11g ? kindly help

Comment: select * from v$session to start...

Comment: thanks a lot but how do i find the number of times a user had logged in to find the average session

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close as NARQ.  Off topic because it belongs on DBA.SE, perhaps.  But it is a perfectly understandable question.

Comment: How come it is closed ?? i am surprised .. it is a very clear  question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Oracle does not audit things like user access.  There are built-in options, but they are switched off by default.

To enable Oracle's audit trail, we need to set the AUDIT_TRAIL parameter.  Set it to `DB` to have records written to a table; this is more convenient for querying than an OS file (unless your `grep` is better than your SQL).  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/security.htm#i16445).

To monitor user connections and disconnections, ask a DBA to issue the following statement:

```
AUDIT SESSION;
```

Then you can write your query off the [DBA_AUDIT_SESSION](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_3071.htm#sthref1673) view.  Something like:

```
select USERNAME
       , avg(LOGOFF_TIME - TIMESTAMP)
from DBA_AUDIT_SESSION
group by USERNAME;
```

Note that this is on;y going to give you meaningful information if you have an application with Old Skool named user accounts.  Web applications with connection pooling will all be audited as the same user, so you will need to write a bespoke logging tool.

Comment: I created a new table from v$session and from that table i calculated the average session time ..